# Loading saved viewpoints from navisworks into forge

Tags: forge, autodesk-navisworks

Is it possible to load saved viewpoints from navisworks into the forge viewer? We are currently having to save a model multiple times and then load multiple times. If we can bring in saved viewpoints the process would be much better.
Thanks
Daniel